# In a MIPS Assembly Array declaration, what happens if you put a number other than 0 as the first space in the array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

When you declare an empty array in MIPS Assembly, you would write:

```
Array: .word 0:4
```

What happens if you write   `Array: .word 1:4` or `Array: .word 3:5` or any number in the first place?

I have tried it in MARS and have not seen any side effects. Thank you!

Comment: I guess, in all cases, array with size (last-first+1) is declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array declaration syntax is

```
.<type> <initial-value>:<count>
```

So, `.word 1:4` means "create an array of four words, each initialized to *1*". If you are treating the array as "empty" and simply writing over the array in your program, you won't see any ill effects because your program doesn't use the "empty" array value.